# How to keep a value current in 2 different nodes in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have a "ratings" with value of "1203". I need these key-value to be in sync in an another Firebase node. How do I do that?

**Details**

I have an article based app. I want to show the article rating and ratings count in the main view controller and also need to show the same values when the article is selected.

There's one node that consists of all the article information (this node is read only by the user), and an another node under a user's uid with relevant information of the article. When someone leaves a rating to an article, I would like to update the rating value under all user nodes.

```
//user-uid
   //auniq4565hfgsHFkgfkRG1
       //ratings: 1233
       //otherInfo: true
//readOnlyNode
   //auniq4565hfgsHFkgfkRG1
      //ratings: 1233
      //lotsOfOtherValues: true
```

I want to keep the "ratings" in sync for all users.

Comment: Either you'll need to update both places in one go, or you'll need a separate process that updates the second place when the first one changes. I don't really see any other flavors here.

Comment: I think it might be very expensive in my case because I would have to update the change to all users that has that value. Well, I think I should take that feature off since the cost is too high.

Comment: With the limited information you've provided it's hard to recommend one way or the other. It's very much a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I recommend reading that link, and updating this question to explain what you're trying to accomplish and how duplicating data (which is incredibly common in NoSQL databases) is going to cost you too much. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) too for a good overview.